# Jekyll Cannot Be Deployed on Manjaro Linux - Sass-Listen-4.0.0 Cannot Be Installed On Deployment (GitLab, Netlify)

Tags: ruby, gitlab, jekyll, netlify, manjaro

I cannot get my website to work on either GitLab Pages or Netlify. Trying to use either service to upload my Jekyll Website and host it returns an error about sass-listen not being able to be installed on either platform. Shown below is the version of the application I am using to make the Jekyll website and deploy from.

```
> ruby -v

ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]

> bundle -v

Bundler Version 1.16.2

> lsb_release -a

LSB Version:    n/a
Distributor ID: ManjaroLinux
Description:    Manjaro Linux
Release:        17.1.10
Codename:       Hakoila

> bundle update

The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Using public_suffix 3.0.2
Using addressable 2.5.2
Using bundler 1.16.2
Using colorator 1.1.0
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
Using eventmachine 1.2.7
Using http_parser.rb 0.6.0
Using em-websocket 0.5.1
Using ffi 1.9.25
Using forwardable-extended 2.6.0
Using i18n 0.9.5
Using rb-inotify 0.9.10
Using sass-listen 4.0.0
Using sass 3.5.6
Using jekyll-sass-converter 1.5.2
Using rb-fsevent 0.10.3
Using ruby_dep 1.5.0
Using listen 3.1.5
Using jekyll-watch 2.0.0
Using kramdown 1.17.0
Using liquid 4.0.0
Using mercenary 0.3.6
Using pathutil 0.16.1
Using rouge 3.1.1
Using safe_yaml 1.0.4
Using jekyll 3.8.3
Using jekyll-menus 0.6.0
Bundle updated!

> bundle install

Using public_suffix 3.0.2
Using addressable 2.5.2
Using bundler 1.16.2
Using colorator 1.1.0
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
Using eventmachine 1.2.7
Using http_parser.rb 0.6.0
Using em-websocket 0.5.1
Using ffi 1.9.25
Using forwardable-extended 2.6.0
Using i18n 0.9.5
Using rb-inotify 0.9.10
Using sass-listen 4.0.0
Using sass 3.5.6
Using jekyll-sass-converter 1.5.2
Using rb-fsevent 0.10.3
Using ruby_dep 1.5.0
Using listen 3.1.5
Using jekyll-watch 2.0.0
Using kramdown 1.17.0
Using liquid 4.0.0
Using mercenary 0.3.6
Using pathutil 0.16.1
Using rouge 3.1.1
Using safe_yaml 1.0.4
Using jekyll 3.8.3
Using jekyll-menus 0.6.0
Bundle complete! 3 Gemfile dependencies, 27 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

> cat ./Gemfile
source "https://rubygems.org"

    # Hello! This is where you manage which Jekyll version is used to run.
    # When you want to use a different version, change it below, save the
    # file and run `bundle install`. Run Jekyll with `bundle exec`, like so:
    #
    #     bundle exec jekyll serve
    #
    # This will help ensure the proper Jekyll version is running.
    # Happy Jekylling!
    gem "jekyll", "~> 3.8.3"


    # This is the default theme for new Jekyll sites. You may change this to anything you like.

    # If you want to use GitHub Pages, remove the "gem "jekyll"" above and
    # uncomment the line below. To upgrade, run `bundle update github-pages`.
    # gem "github-pages", group: :jekyll_plugins

    # If you have any plugins, put them here!
    group :jekyll_plugins do
      gem "jekyll-menus"
    end


# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

# Performance-booster for watching directories on Windows
gem "wdm", "~> 0.1.0" if Gem.win_platform?

> cat ./Gemfile.lock

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    addressable (2.5.2)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 4.0)
    colorator (1.1.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
    em-websocket (0.5.1)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.9)
      http_parser.rb (~> 0.6.0)
    eventmachine (1.2.7)
    ffi (1.9.25)
    forwardable-extended (2.6.0)
    http_parser.rb (0.6.0)
    i18n (0.9.5)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jekyll (3.8.3)
      addressable (~> 2.4)
      colorator (~> 1.0)
      em-websocket (~> 0.5)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      jekyll-sass-converter (~> 1.0)
      jekyll-watch (~> 2.0)
      kramdown (~> 1.14)
      liquid (~> 4.0)
      mercenary (~> 0.3.3)
      pathutil (~> 0.9)
      rouge (>= 1.7, < 4)
      safe_yaml (~> 1.0)
    jekyll-menus (0.6.0)
      jekyll (~> 3.1)
    jekyll-sass-converter (1.5.2)
      sass (~> 3.4)
    jekyll-watch (2.0.0)
      listen (~> 3.0)
    kramdown (1.17.0)
    liquid (4.0.0)
    listen (3.1.5)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
      ruby_dep (~> 1.2)
    mercenary (0.3.6)
    pathutil (0.16.1)
      forwardable-extended (~> 2.6)
    public_suffix (3.0.2)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
    rb-inotify (0.9.10)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0, < 2)
    rouge (3.1.1)
    ruby_dep (1.5.0)
    safe_yaml (1.0.4)
    sass (3.5.6)
      sass-listen (>= 4.0.0)
    sass-listen (4.0.0)
      rb-inotify (>= 0.9.7, >= 0.9)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  jekyll (~> 3.8.3)
  jekyll-menus
  tzinfo-data

BUNDLED WITH
   1.16.2
```

When I try to deploy to either GitLab or Netlify, here is the exact error I get. I have tried switching Ruby Versions, Pushing without the Ruby GemLock file, Making an entirely new Jekyll Site and running "bundle install" on it, Removing and Adding Plugins, and running "bundle install --full-index" All of the following return the same error on both deployment platforms.

On Netlify:

```
6:13:50 PM: Build ready to start
6:13:51 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
6:13:52 PM: Failed to fetch cache, continuing with build
6:13:52 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
6:13:52 PM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
6:13:52 PM: git clone git@gitlab.com:ReasonablySelenium/netlify-debugging-project
6:13:54 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
6:13:55 PM: Starting build script
6:13:55 PM: Installing dependencies
6:13:56 PM: Downloading and installing node v8.11.3...
6:13:56 PM: Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.11.3/node-v8.11.3-linux-x64.tar.xz...
6:13:56 PM: 
#
6:13:56 PM:                                   1.8%
6:13:57 PM: 
##################
6:13:57 PM:                      25.4%
6:13:57 PM: 
############################################                              61.6%
6:13:57 PM: 
################################
6:13:57 PM: ######################################## 100.0%
6:13:57 PM: Computing checksum with sha256sum
6:13:57 PM: Checksums matched!
6:13:59 PM: Now using node v8.11.3 (npm v5.6.0)
6:14:00 PM: Attempting ruby version 2.3.6, read from environment
6:14:01 PM: Using ruby version 2.3.6
6:14:02 PM: Using PHP version 5.6
6:14:02 PM: Started restoring cached ruby gems
6:14:02 PM: Finished restoring cached ruby gems
6:14:02 PM: Installing gem bundle
6:14:03 PM: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/
6:14:03 PM: .
6:14:03 PM: .
6:14:03 PM: .
6:14:03 PM: .
6:14:04 PM: .
6:14:04 PM: .
6:14:04 PM: .
6:14:04 PM: .
6:14:04 PM: .
6:14:04 PM: .
6:14:04 PM: .
6:14:05 PM: Fetching public_suffix 3.0.2
6:14:05 PM: Installing public_suffix 3.0.2
6:14:05 PM: Fetching addressable 2.5.2
6:14:05 PM: Installing addressable 2.5.2
6:14:05 PM: Using bundler 1.16.2
6:14:05 PM: Fetching colorator 1.1.0
6:14:05 PM: Installing colorator 1.1.0
6:14:05 PM: Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
6:14:05 PM: Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
6:14:06 PM: Fetching eventmachine 1.2.7
6:14:06 PM: Installing eventmachine 1.2.7 with native extensions
6:14:23 PM: Fetching http_parser.rb 0.6.0
6:14:23 PM: Installing http_parser.rb 0.6.0 with native extensions
6:14:24 PM: Fetching em-websocket 0.5.1
6:14:25 PM: Installing em-websocket 0.5.1
6:14:25 PM: Fetching ffi 1.9.25
6:14:25 PM: Installing ffi 1.9.25 with native extensions
6:14:34 PM: Fetching forwardable-extended 2.6.0
6:14:35 PM: Installing forwardable-extended 2.6.0
6:14:35 PM: Fetching i18n 0.9.5
6:14:35 PM: Installing i18n 0.9.5
6:14:35 PM: Fetching rb-inotify 0.9.10
6:14:35 PM: Installing rb-inotify 0.9.10
6:14:35 PM: Fetching sass-listen 4.0.0
6:14:35 PM: Downloading sass-listen-4.0.0 revealed dependencies not in the API or the
6:14:35 PM: lockfile (rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.4, ~> 0.9), rb-inotify (>= 0.9.7, ~> 0.9)).
6:14:35 PM: Either installing with `--full-index` or running `bundle update sass-listen`
6:14:35 PM: should fix the problem.
6:14:35 PM: In Gemfile:
6:14:35 PM:   minima was resolved to 2.5.0, which depends on
6:14:35 PM:     jekyll-feed was resolved to 0.10.0, which depends on
6:14:35 PM:       jekyll was resolved to 3.8.3, which depends on
6:14:35 PM:         jekyll-sass-converter was resolved to 1.5.2, which depends on
6:14:35 PM:           sass was resolved to 3.5.6, which depends on
6:14:35 PM:             sass-listen
6:14:35 PM: Error during gem install
6:14:35 PM: Error running command: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
6:14:35 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
6:14:35 PM: failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
6:14:35 PM: Finished processing build request in 44.176883866s
```

On GitLab:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.0.0-rc1 (6dcccded)
  on docker-auto-scale ed2dce3a
Using Docker executor with image ruby:2.3 ...
Pulling docker image ruby:2.3 ...
Using docker image sha256:da0014e956b4cd42c7a08393a84f937a8d9c8a90de2e765ad04e73ab37abb945 for ruby:2.3 ...
Running on runner-ed2dce3a-project-7166488-concurrent-0 via runner-ed2dce3a-srm-1529693929-b4ef16ac...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/ReasonablySelenium/rozlan-society.gitlab.io'...
Checking out 53ea4d7e as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching public_suffix 3.0.2
Installing public_suffix 3.0.2
Fetching addressable 2.5.2
Installing addressable 2.5.2
Using bundler 1.16.2
Fetching colorator 1.1.0
Installing colorator 1.1.0
Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
Fetching eventmachine 1.2.7
Installing eventmachine 1.2.7 with native extensions
Fetching http_parser.rb 0.6.0
Installing http_parser.rb 0.6.0 with native extensions
Fetching em-websocket 0.5.1
Installing em-websocket 0.5.1
Fetching ffi 1.9.25
Installing ffi 1.9.25 with native extensions
Fetching forwardable-extended 2.6.0
Installing forwardable-extended 2.6.0
Fetching i18n 0.9.5
Installing i18n 0.9.5
Fetching rb-inotify 0.9.10
Installing rb-inotify 0.9.10
Fetching sass-listen 4.0.0
Downloading sass-listen-4.0.0 revealed dependencies not in the API or the
lockfile (rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.4, ~> 0.9), rb-inotify (>= 0.9.7, ~> 0.9)).
Either installing with `--full-index` or running `bundle update sass-listen`
should fix the problem.

In Gemfile:
  jekyll-menus was resolved to 0.6.0, which depends on
    jekyll was resolved to 3.8.3, which depends on
      jekyll-sass-converter was resolved to 1.5.2, which depends on
        sass was resolved to 3.5.6, which depends on
          sass-listen
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I am not sure what I am supposed to do at this point. Can somebody please out me out?

EDIT:
I tried using updated libraries today and it didn't work. I have since moved on from Jekyll for some time now, so I don't want to bother fixing the problem and move on to something else if I have to. Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Have you tried the recommended solution in the error? `bundle update sass-listen`
I would think that would add the missing dependencies when ran locally then you would commit the changes on the repository.

Comment: When I used "bundle update sass-listen", this is the result: Bundler attempted to update sass-listen but its version stayed the same. @talves Git says everything is up to date.

Comment: I also get ```Bundler attempted to update sass-listen but its version stayed the same```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This solved the problem for me:**

- `rm Gemfile.lock`
- Install without using system as vendor: `bundle install --path=vendor`

Source: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/59429